# Can I use divert as an alternative to ipfw fwd?

Tags: freebsd, firewall

I would like to lead some traffic through a transparent proxy (which actually is on another server and connected with an ssh tunnel).

Normally I could do this:

```
ipfw add forward localhost,8080 tcp from any to x.x.x.x 80
```

However, fwd/forward needs a re-compile of the kernel, which I am not happy to do. Therefore, I'm searching for a solution that doesn't need a recompile.

For example, could I somehow use a divert socket to implement this? Or are there any other basic good solutions?

Comment: ipfw divert requires as well to re-compile your kernel. Why being to unhappy about this ?

Comment: @Ouki No, ipfw divert can be loaded as module (ipdivert_load="YES" in loader.conf)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. divert can be used only with software that listens on sockets created with `IPPROTO_IPDIVERT`, but proxy servers usually listen on TCP ports.

Have you tried to use another firewalls for this purpose? http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy#Interception_Caching_packet_redirection_for_Solaris.2C_SunOS.2C_and_BSD_systems

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a look on `rinetd` (`~ports/net/rinetd`).

This is a very simple port redirector (from one ip/port to another).
The re-direction is done through its configuration file `rinted.conf`:

```
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport
1.2.3.4         8080      4.3.2.1         80
```

Divert is usually used for more wide port selections (ie like all from 1 interface to natd ;).